# Set-PSReadLineOption: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PredictionViewStyle'

Tags: powershell, terminal, psreadline

I'm trying to change the -PredictionViewStyle option of PSReadline, but I got the error "Set-PSReadLineOption: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PredictionViewStyle'."

It's a fresh install and  Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History works.

Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Restarting my shell solved it...

Answer (score 9):

## Open PowerShell

```
pwsh.exe -noprofile -command "Install-Module PSReadLine -Force -AllowPrerelease -SkipPublisherCheck"

Install-Module PSReadLine -Force

notepad $profile

Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionSource History

Set-PSReadLineOption -PredictionViewStyle ListView
```

#### Save (cntrl + S)

#### Restart Terminal

Comment: As I have an older version of PowerShell the first command (`pwsh.exe ...`) failed. Instead I opened `cmd.exe` and ran `powershell.exe -noprofile -command "Install-Module PSReadLine -Force -AllowPrerelease -SkipPublisherCheck"` and continued with the rest of the commands in a PowerShell window.

Answer (score 0):

In powershell itself, instead of pwsh.exe I ran powershell.exe and then everything else.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).